# How to bake all animation at once

Tags: animation

I have a complex animation with a lot of objects using-Shape keys, Nla tracks, particle systems, physics, path following...

But to use a render farm you need to bake everything to key frames.

Is there a way to select all and bake? Or correct me if I'm wrong about something
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure they're asking you to bake all to *keyframes* and not just that any physics, like particles, need to be baked to a cache?

Comment: Try asking them directly what they mean.

Comment: Yeah, its true. You only need to bake physics to cache. :)

Comment: @Cimo Can you make your insight into an answer, please?